# WCF communication on Http

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, https, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service which works fine when accessed internally. The WCF link is 
.

I requested the network team at our organization to expose this WCF to outside world since public websites will access this WCF. I gave the network team DNS as somewebsite.com and IP address of the server on which WCF is hosted.

After getting the confirmation from Network team (they use Juniper network ) that they have made the required settings to make the WCF available to outside world I tested it as an external user.

If I type in http://somewebsite.com/LookUp.svc on address bar I get http 404 page not found error. However if I replace http with httpS as  then I see the WCF information. To further test it , I added a simple html file to the root of the website and opened as 
http://somewebsite.com/test.html. The Test.html does not open when http is used. However it I use httpS as  then Test.html page is displayed to outside users.

The WCF is hosted to windows 2008 R2 and is communicating over port 80 and I have also added the site binding as  somewebsite.com with Type as Http and port as 80.

Any idea why WCF caanot be accseed over http ?. I want it to be accessed over http only ?. The WCF uses basicHttpBinding

Is the setting wrong on server on which WCF is hosted ?
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

If the service worked before over http before your network guys opened the firewalls I would suggest that they have only enabled the firewall for https traffic.

Sounds like a firewall/routing problem to me...

HTH

Comment: internally http works even now. HTTP has not worked ever since network guys made the changes. I would like to  do some homework before going back to them :)