# WCF on https without SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7, windows-firewall

Is it possible to provide WCF over https instead of http without setting SSL configuration in IIS 7.5 ?

We have a wcf as http://service.com/service.svc . Internally I can access as http://service.com/service.svc but when external users access it..they are default redirected to https://service.com/service.svc. HttpS link not http. Browser displays the wcf information for users but only when accessed as https.

When users outside the network access using WCFTestClient..they get this error

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://service.com/service.svc 
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, 
please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error
URI: https://service.com/service.svc 
 Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://service.com

However WCF cab be is accessed as http://service.com/service.svc on WCFtestclient internally but not as https://service.com/service.svc on testclient or on browser.

Any idea how to resolve this error...?? Could it be firewall is passing all request to https for external users.

Here is my earlier post regarding same issue in detail..

[WCF communication on Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388912/wcf-communication-on-http)

Since I cannot make the WCF available  to out side users as Http..I wanted to see if I can make it available at https without out going through SSL.

Comment: i think the way this can be achieved is to configure your settings to include-                                                 <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="nameofthebindingHttps" behaviorConfiguration="(yourinfo)" contract="{yourinfo}"/>

Comment: Why would you want to use https without setting the SSL configuration?

Comment: I just updated my question with more detail.

Comment: I got more information regarding the issue from Network Team. We are using JUniper network for reverse proxy. It allows transfic only as as HTTPS with its own SSL certificate. SO I was asked to expose the WCF as HTTPS. How can I achieve this  without I having to create a SSL certificate at my end ?.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough background information. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to do some basic authentication? Or you want to usevhttps but you haven't bought a ssl certificate yet?!?